# How to wrap content of a li element with html tag in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I wrap content of li element using jQuery? My HTML code looks like this:

```
 <div id="ident">
<ul>
            <li>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With wrapInner():

```
 $("div#ident li").wrapInner("<div>");
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Answer (score 0):

have a look 
http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: This will wrap the `<li>` itself, not it's content. You're a) producing invalid HTML and b) not answering the user's question.